# Is it possible to manually import product images to Nopcommerce

Tags: ftp, nopcommerce

currently the import function is not working for product images, so is it possible to FTP the images onto the site. I noticed that stock images are stored in the /wwwroot/Content/Images/Thumbs/. So if I was to add product images would they go there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual issue was there some sort of problem importing the images with the product details. So instead I created a path for the product images, in the products details and then manually placed all the images into the wwwroot/Content/images/Thumbs/ folder. It seemed to have worked!

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 options,
1) storing on the local drive or CDN: in this case NC should convert your images in its format and name convention. Therefore when you import 1 image (do a test on the admin panel) you can see how it is stored under Images folder.

you can see the  Libraries\Nop.Services\ExportImport\ImportManager.cs, funciton is called ImportProductsFromXlsx. this function is normally reading from xlsx file and looping through each defined line. you can create your own funciton by using this which can read from your DB (get path information all you need) and let to convert each images.

2) Store as binary into picture table: this is same procedure as described above. all you have to do is the define in the settings that you want to store as binary.